# How to overwrite files using robocopy regardless of their last change date

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I want my PowerShell script to take a backup of `$destination` directory, in `$backup` directory, but the newly created backup directory should be named `$destination-{yyyy-dd-mm}` where 'yyyy-dd-mm' is today's date.

I have written my 1st ever PowerShell script which accomplishes the job with one caeat. I have noticed that it creates a folder if it does not exist already and copies all the files into this folder the 1st time it is executed, but on subsequent runs it **skips** all files, if there is no change. I want to forcefully overwrite the destination files regardless of their last change date.

```
"START"

$source = "C:\Sandbox\Source"
$destination = "C:\Sandbox\Target"
$backup = "C:\Backups\"

"Taking backup of '$destination' in '$backup'"

$currentDate = Get-Date
$currentDate = $currentDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
$something = $backup + "Staging-" + $currentDate
robocopy $targetPath $something /E /V /MT /Z

"END"
```

Comment: If you just want to copy, you could use the `copy` command. `robocopy` is made for synching.

Answer (score 2):

#### I want to forcefully overwrite the destination files regardless of their last change date.

Use the `/IS` switch - Include Same, overwrite files even if they are already the same where `Same` is a file class:

[image]

Source: [Robocopy "Robust File Copy" - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html#fileclasses)

Answer (score -1):

The robocopy argument you want, is " /IS".

$Arguments = @( '/IS', '/R:0', '/W:0', '/MT', '/E', '/A-:SH' )

$RoboCopy = 'C:\Windows\System32\Robocopy.exe'

$RoboCopyArgs = @($Source, $Destination, $Name) + $Arguments

& $RoboCopy @RoboCopyArgs

I have this robocopy powershell script for you.
Hope you'll find it usefull.

https://www.tapuz.co.il/threads/%D7%94%D7%A2%D7%AA%D7%A7-%D7%A7%D7%91%D7%A6%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%95%D7%95%D7%93%D7%90-%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%94%D7%A2%D7%AA%D7%A7.15635089/post-145607055

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1227717)